# Eliminar divs previamente creados con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando unos gráficos con `Highcharts`, el cual se muestran luego de recibir una petición `Ajax` y una opción de un formulario. Depende de la opción se deberían crear **n** cantidad de `<div>` y adentro de los `<div>` mostrar la gráfica.

La petición, la opción del formulario y crear los `<div>` funciona correctamente, el problema viene al eliminar los `<div>` previamente creados a la hora de elegir otra opción, ya que, solo borra el contenido de dichos `<div>` pero siguen ahí por así decirlo.

- Eligiendo una opción:

[image: opcion #1]

- Luego, eligiendo otra opción:

[image: opcion #2]

Los `<div>` los creo de la siguiente forma (utilizando `append`):

- Archivo **"indicadores.js"**

```
function opcion_uno()
{
    var fila = $(".cajas");
    var box = $(".box-charts");
    box.text("");

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        fila.append('<div class="col-6 box-charts p-2 my-4" id="container'+ i +'" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');
    }

    Highcharts.chart('container0', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
}

function opcion_dos()
{
    var fila = $(".cajas");
    var box = $(".box-charts");
    box.text("");

    for(let i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        fila.append('<div class="col-6 box-charts p-2 my-4" id="container'+ i +'" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');
    }

    Highcharts.chart('container0', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
}
```

- **Ajax**

```
$(".formulario").change(function (){

    var select = $("#lista").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"modules/ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: select,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(){
            switch(select)
            {
                case '1':
                    return opcion_uno();
                case '2':
                    return opcion_dos();
                default:
                    console.log("opcion no valida");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

- **Html**

```html
<div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">

        <div class="col-12">
            <form method="POST">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Lista</span>
                        </div>

                        <select class="custom-select formulario form-control" id="lista" name="lista">
                            <option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                            <option value="1">Opcion #1</option>
                            <option value="2">Opcion #2</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="cajas col-12"></div>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/indicadores.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas asignandole un valor vacio a tus divs, al hacer el box.text(""); lo que necesitas hacer es removerlos, prueba con esto box.remove(); en cada una de tus funciones, deberia de funcionar.

Comment: Antes del ajax, `$(".box-charts").remove();` y ya está, si no entendí mal.

Comment: Si, así es, funcionaria mejor, pero ya vez que el en sus funciones hace esto para eliminar sus gráficas box.text(""), por eso le recomendé que reemplazara eso por el box.remove().

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gracias a los comentarios de [@Ricardo Pérez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30865/ricardo-p%c3%a9rez) y [@Emeeus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/96928/emeeus), lo único que hacia falta era cambiar el `.text()` por `.remove()` en mis funciones.

- Antes:

```
function opcion_uno()
{
    var fila = $(".cajas");
    var box = $(".box-charts");
    box.text("");
.
.
.
```

- Ahora:

```
function opcion_uno()
{
    var fila = $(".cajas");
    var box = $(".box-charts");
    box.remove();
.
.
.
```